# I am not understanding this example of Chebychev Inequality?

Tags: probability, distributions, sample-size

I am trying to teach myself statistics and am reading DeGroot's book. Anyways, I'm in Chebychev's Inequality and am confused by this example:

[image]

[image]

I understand the second part about if we know the distribution beforehand, we get a smaller required  equal to 15.  However, I am unable to replicate the first part based on the definition of Chebychev's inequality.

[image]

I tried the following. Pr(0.4 <= Xbar <= 0.6) should be the same thing as Pr(abs(Xbar - μ) <= 0.1) and so:

> Pr(abs(Xbar - μ) >= 0.1) <= σ^2 / (n * 0.1^2)

We know the variance of the distribution is n * (0.5) * (1 - 0.5) since its binomial.  However, when I plug that variance in, obviously the ns cancel out and we are unable to find the necessary sample size.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I also don't understand his explanation and why he approaches the problem the way he does.  I understand the left hand side of his answer and realize he plugs in T/n as the sample mean.  I don't get how he got the right hand side.

Thanks!

Comment: The $n$'s don't cancel _completely._ See my Answer details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First issue. Evaluating the bound.** In Chebychev's Inequality,

$$P\left(\left|T -\frac n2\right| \le \frac{n}{10}\right) \le 1 - \frac{V(T)}{(n/10)^2}
= 1 - \frac{n/4}{n^2/100}\\ = 1 - \frac{100n}{4n^2} = 1 - \frac{25}{n}.$$

**Second issue: probability and bound change with sample size.**
For $n = 84,$ Chebyshev's Inequality says

$$P(.4n \le T \le .6n) = P(33.6 \le T \le 50.6)\\
= P(34 \le T \le 50) \le 1 - 25/84 = 0.7024.$$

The exact probability is $P(34 \le T \le 50) = 0.9370,$ as computed in R.

```
sum(dbinom(34:50, 84, .5))
[1] 0.9370277
```

For $n = 15,$ the Chebyshev bound is useless; we already know the probability is positive: $P(6 \le T \le 9) \le 1 - 25/15
= -0.6667.\,$
The exact probability is $0.6982 \approx 0.7,$ as claimed. This is just the author's way of saying that the Chebychev bound isn't very useful
in a particular practical application.

```
sum(dbinom(6:9, 15, .5))
[1] 0.6982422
```

Because the mean and variance of $T$ depend on $n,$ you have to use
one value of $n$ at a time.